# Oracle query returning a manager that's not terminated PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm currently re-writing a query and would like to improvise it.

My website has the following structure:

> DEPARTMENT:
>
> Highest level attainable
>
> EMPLOYEE_VIEW VIEW:
>
> View containing all employee related information
>
> SERVICE AREA GROUP:
>
> Child of a department
>
> SERVICE AREA:
>
> Child of a service area group
>
> SERVICE_AREA TABLE:
>
> Table containing the service areas
>
> SERVICE_AREA_EMPLOYEE:
>
> Table containing employee relation to the service area table.

Each department, service area group, and service area has one manager.
The query currently returns active staff (STAFF) and managers (MGR) primary sequences.
It does this by using a **function** that will query to see if the current employee sequence throws a **NO_DATA_FOUND** exception.

Function called:

```
FUNCTION GETSERVICEAREAMGREMPSEQ(   ARG_EMP_SEQ NUMBER,
                                    ARG_POS_SEQ NUMBER,
                                    ARG_FLAG CHAR
                                ) RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        INTOUTPUT NUMBER;
BEGIN

BEGIN
SELECT DECODE(ARG_FLAG, 'E', ARG_EMP_SEQ, VS.POSITION_SEQ) INTO INTOUTPUT FROM SCHEMA.EMPLOYEE_VIEW VS WHERE VS.EMPLOYEE_SEQ = ARG_EMP_SEQ
AND VS.TERMINATION_DATE IS NULL;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        BEGIN

            SELECT DECODE(ARG_FLAG, 'E', VS.EMPLOYEE_SEQ, ARG_POS_SEQ)  INTO INTOUTPUT FROM SCHEMA.EMPLOYEE_VIEW VS WHERE VS.POSITION_SEQ = ARG_POS_SEQ
            AND VS.TERMINATION_DATE IS NULL AND ROWNUM=1;

                EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    INTOUTPUT := -1;

        END;

     WHEN OTHERS THEN
        INTOUTPUT := -1;

END;
RETURN INTOUTPUT;
END;
```

If the NO_DATA_FOUND exception also throws an exception then it won't match anyone for that service area.

Can this be done in a single query without functions?

Comment: Questions 2 and 3 are off-topic for S.O, you should remove them. For question 1, add some sample data and expected output and  remember,  **only** in plain text format, no images.

Comment: You could probably combine the two queries using `where (vs.employee_seq = arg_emp_seq or vs.position_seq = arg_pos_seq)`, adding an `order by` to ensure that your preferred match is returned first, and filter to get the first row only (the technique to do that will vary by Oracle version).